# Why git's prompt keep coming up?

Tags: git

All of the sudden git keeps prompting me for identification:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <>) not allowed
```

It's coming up on every commit now. Public SSH key on the computer matches the one stored in repo settings. Is there anything I need to check ?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or any other GIT UI tool along side git shell?

Comment: @MohanaRao No, I'm not. Just vanilla Linux terminal.

Comment: Are you using any sort of fancy dotfiles or prompt settings?  Some people have reported prompt frameworks causing problems with this.

Comment: Git can't read user.name and user.email from any level of git configuration. In the terminal, run commands as the log says.

Answer (score 0):

> Public SSH key on the computer matches the one stored in repo settings

This is for remote authentication, not for local commit authorship.

Check the output of `git config --global -l`.
If you don't see `user.name`/`user.email`, add them:

```
git config --global user.name myname
git config --global user.email my@email.com
```

Comment: `git config --global -l` prints out the values I keep setting to it before each commit. The question is rather why git keeps prompting me knowing the values are already set.

Comment: @wood because you have set `user.mail` instead of `user.email`?

Comment: No, I didn't but nice try :)

Comment: @wood Is it possible you are doing those `git` commands with a different user? (or `sudo`), thereby not accessing the regular global Git config which does include your `user.name`/`user.email`?